# How can I identify a chinese char?

Tags: c++, char

I am working on a project which reading chinese characters as input. I have a function which returning
as true if it is a chinese char.

I have a problem. When I read this chinese char:〇. It returns false. How can I identify this char? What is the wrong in my code?

```
//this calls first
inline bool isChineseChar(wchar_t ch) {
    bool retVal = IsIdeograph(ch); //Returning as false
    return retVal; 
};

const wchar_t FIRST_KANA = 0x3040;
const wchar_t LAST_KANA = 0x30ff;
const wchar_t FIRST_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPH = 0x4e00;
const wchar_t LAST_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPH = 0x9fcf;
const wchar_t FIRST_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPH = 0xf900;
const wchar_t LAST_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPH = 0xfaff;

/// CJK Unified Ideographs (Han) and CJK Compatibility Ideographs
bool IsIdeograph(wchar_t c)
{
    return ( ( c>=FIRST_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPH && c<=LAST_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPH) 
             || (c>=FIRST_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPH && c<=LAST_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPH)
             || (c>=FIRST_KANA && c<=LAST_KANA)
           );
}
```

Comment: What is the encoding of `wchar_t`? ie. windows or linux?

Comment: It is on windows. I use GB18030 codepage.

Comment: ok, so it's UTF-16. `When I read this chinese char:〇.` How exactly do you "read" it? Why not just `std::cout << (int)c` and see what value is that?

Comment: I read from a database. I see every char in debug. I loop over the chinese strings. And I call the function (isChineseChar) to every char. Everythings looks good except this char. I don't know why. It's always return false. But it is a chinese char too..

Comment: Well, it looks like it's below 3040 https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3007

Comment: Thanks. And how can i edit my code?

Comment: @theshepherd do you understand how the code works *now*?

Comment: Trying to understand. IsIdeograph function from here: https://www.programcreek.com/cpp/?CodeExample=is+cjk+unicode

Comment: Your code does not include all Chinese characters in Unicode.  You'll need to add more code for acceptable Unicode ranges or specific Unicode codepoints.  q.v. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/scripts/Hani